# Laravel blade duplicating multiple buttons

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I'm trying to show only **one close button** if a post belongs to a user by using utilize blade [authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#via-blade-templates) however im getting this

[image]

The policy and server side runs ok and i can click the button and it will do as i need it to do, but i only need to see one close button for each post, however maybe im compacting the posts incorrectly.

html

```
 <div id="mypost" class="col-md-8 panel-default" ng-repeat="post in myposts">
        <div id="eli-style-heading" class="panel-heading"><% post.title %></div>
            <div class="panel-body panel">
                <figure>
                    <p> <% post.body %></p>
                   <p> by: <% post.user.name %></p>
                   <p>  <% post.created_at %></p>

                </figure>
                <span>


            @foreach($posts as $post)
                @if(Auth::user()->can('delete',$post))
                 <i style="color:red;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="deletePost(post)"></i>
                @endif
            @endforeach

                </span>
            </div>
    </div>
```

**PostController.php** (the view for the posts page)

```
public function index()
{

    $posts = Post::with('user')->get();

    return view('home', compact('posts'));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about php so i am writing simple text only

Its because you are using `foreach` inside ng-repeat 
 Change

```
@foreach($posts as $post)// this is the problem 
                @if(Auth::user()->can('delete',$post))
                 <i style="color:red;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="deletePost(post)"></i>
                @endif
            @endforeach
```

to

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
                @if(Auth::user()->can('delete',$post) && here add some condition like  $post.id(php)==post.id(angular))
                 <i style="color:red;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="deletePost(post)"></i>
                @endif
            @endforeach
```

Or

```
@if(userIsAuthrise){
 <i style="color:red;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="deletePost(post)"></i>
}
```

Comment: `@foreach($posts as $post)
                @if(Auth::user()->can('delete',$post) && here add some condition like  $post.id(php)==post.id(angular))
                 <i style="color:red;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="deletePost(post)"></i>
                @endif
            @endforeach`

Comment: multiple buttons still

Comment: @BARNOWL you have to replace `here add some condition like $post.id(php)==post.id(angular)` this  with a condition that can ensure that will be true only for one item

Comment: just change you code to `<i style="color:red;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="deletePost(post)"></i>` and remove @foreach and @if and see the magic

Comment: i get this 

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$post'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159125/discussion-between-jitender-and-barnowl).